# Combine org-sparse-tree and ivy-swiper to search keywords in a structured way

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When using C-s which conjure `ivy-swiper` to search keywords,
the headings without the desired results will stay unfolded and thus I have to focus on the mini-buffer to reference the results.

[image]

Please notice that heading above without `sparse` are expanded.

As a solution, I construct a sparse tree in advance with C-s followed to search.  (C-c / r sparse and C-s)

The headings not qualified are folded.
this way, I can focus on the current buffer comfortable and take mini-buffer just as a reference.

[image]

How could combine them together by a function?
so when invoke it to search 'sparse`, the function first construct a sparse tree then swiper to search within the tree.